# what is the instance argument passed to the update method in ListSerializer in the django rest documentation

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

what is the instance argument passed to the .update() method in ListSerializer in the django rest documentation.([link to documentation ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)).

```
class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
        book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
        data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

        # Perform creations and updates.
        ret = []
        for book_id, data in data_mapping.items():
            book = book_mapping.get(book_id, None)
            if book is None:
                ret.append(self.child.create(data))
            else:
                ret.append(self.child.update(book, data))

        # Perform deletions.
        for book_id, book in book_mapping.items():
            if book_id not in data_mapping:
                book.delete()

        return ret

class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # We need to identify elements in the list using their primary key,
    # so use a writable field here, rather than the default which would be read-only.
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = BookListSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the test cases for DRF's `ListSerializer` class, you can see it is suppose to pass a list of dicts:

Ref:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f148e4e2593e55c76c746c85422924c33ec435cc/tests/test_serializer_lists.py#L390

Comment: serializer = BookSerializer(instance=request.data,data=[],many=True)[a subclasss of serializers.ModelSerializer].this is how I am calling the serializer in my views [subclass of APIView class]. and then `code` if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`code`

Comment: What are we doing with the returned list?  are we going to iterate on the list and use serializer.save(many=False) for each object in the returned list.